# Просмотр логов MySQL

Tags: mysql

Возможно ли просмотреть историю запросов к базе данных в MySQL? И если да то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, в конфигурации MySQL в /etc/mysql/my.cnf в секции [mysqld] пишете:

```
log /var/log/mysql/query.log
```

Перезапускаете сервер `service mysql restart`. Используйте только для DEBUG-режима, потому что лог растет очень быстро в размерах.

Comment: тоесть на хостинге никак не просмотреть логи?

Comment: ну только если хостер предоставляет такую услугу.

Comment: Shamanis, нашел этот конфиг тут /etc/my.cnf дописал строку log /var/log/mysql/query.log, но логи не пишутся, как узнать в чем дело?